# How would I store a form of information temporarily if internet connection is down

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments

So I am making an application in Python where you fill out your information and then pay for the product on the kiosk.

Sometimes these kiosks lose internet connection (due to the poor internet in the buildings)

I need to figure out a way to temporarily store that data (customer information(i.e: first name, last name, shipping address, etc)) and (payment method) if the internet goes offline.

I'm sending the customer info to ShipStation using the ShipStation API, and the payment via Stripe, any clue if I could securely store the data temporarily?

Comment: You could have a database on your local kiosk which would store some user information and then pass it on to your server when a connection is available again. You shouldn't *EVER* store credit card details yourself as that requires that you follow some very detailed and expensive PCI compliance process. If you do need to store payment details locally, it may be wise to look at pre-built POS systems which have this capacity and have cleared the security hurdles.

Comment: @duck I figured the payment information would be a roadblock. I think that we could create an invoice if need be